# Roots of the quadratic eqn

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, quadratics

The question is:
If x satisfies the equation 
$$\left(\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{t^2+2t\cos \alpha +1}\right)x^2 - \left(\int_{-3}^3 \frac{t^2 \sin {2t}dt}{t^2+1}\right)x - 2=0$$
$$(0<\alpha<\pi)$$, then the value of x is:

I know the coefficient of x will equate to zero. And the answer that I got after solving the question does not match with any of the options. So, I'll be grateful if someone can help me out on this one.
Thank You.

Comment: What did you get, and how?

Comment: Please put a title that reflects the question. But... what question ?

Comment: The right answer is the option 3.

Comment: i'm really sorry, I forgot to complete the question actually.

Comment: Delete question, complete question by edit and undelete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the second integral is zero as the integrand function is an odd one and the integration's interval is symmetric wrt zero, so your equation actually is;

$$\left(\int_0^1\frac{dt}{\left(t+\cos\alpha\right)^2+\sin^2\alpha}\right)x^2=2$$

Can you take it from here?

**Added as further hint:**

$$\int\frac{dt}{\sin^2\alpha+(t+\cos\alpha)^2}=\frac1{\sin\alpha}\int\frac{\frac1{\sin\alpha}dt}{1+\left(\frac t{\sin\alpha}+\cot\alpha\right)^2}=\ldots$$

Comment: I still can't get the answer right.

Comment: @Carrick Observe that if $\;f\;$ is some differentiable function, then $$\int\frac{f'(x)}{1+f(x)^2}=\arctan(f(x)) +C ...$$